# using mkdir in tmp folder on mac

Tags: mac, file-permissions, mkdir

when I use

> mkdir /tmp/test

I get the following message

> mkdir: Folder: Permission denied

but when I enclose the file path in double quotes it works

> mkdir "/tmp/test"

first method works when I use sudo

Any reasoning for why 2 works when 1 isn't?

Comment: Using `mkdir /tmp/test` works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure it wasn't just a typo? Is it reproducible?

Comment: Ditto, MJK. I had the same experience.